# alias for table name not working in subquery in terada

Tags: teradata

I am using following query in Teradata:

```
SELECT dt.CUSTOMERID, dt.TEXT, dt.NUMER, dt.DESCRIPTION 
FROM user.sbcustomer_dim dt 
WHERE dt.CUSTOMERID IN( SELECT bt.CUSTOMER_ID FROM user.SBCustomer bt);
```

And it is reporting following error:

```
Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between the 'SELECT' keyword and the 'bt' keyword.
                Statement# 1, Info =122*
```

And If I remove alias from IN() clause, query works fine.

Is alias in subquery not supported in Teradata? (Teradata version: 13.10.00.14)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message carefully you will notice that **bt** is a keyword (shortcut for BEGIN TRANSACTION).

Simply change it to something else.